# Arrayformula to replace sumifs based on criteria - grouping data into categories/types

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

In [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WyrWiQpbXcw4AuFmOiUjOkY-cAeFaOVg1BmPgB9BRls/edit#gid=0)

Cols `G` and `H` give the total of each Account Type, from the data (`A1:D`)

If sum Dr - sum Cr > 0, then only this is shown in col `G`.

`=if(sumifs(C:C,A:A,F2)-sumifs(D:D,A:A,F2)>0, sumifs(C:C,A:A,F2)-sumifs(D:D,A:A,F2),"")`

If sum Cr - sum Dr > 0, then only this is shown in col `H`

`=if(sumifs(D:D,A:A,F2)-sumifs(C:C,A:A,F2)>0, sumifs(D:D,A:A,F2)-sumifs(C:C,A:A,F2),"")`

**I am looking for an array formula which replaces these summifs formula, so that if either new Account Types (e.g. Type E, Type F etc) are added or new rows of data are added, then the formula would automatically calculate the sum Dr or sum Cr, instead of having to copy the formula down**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `query()`, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  lambda( 
    aggregated, 
    lambda( 
      account, balance, 
      { 
        "Account Type", "Dr", "Cr"; 
        account, 
        if( balance >= 0, balance, iferror(1/0) ), 
        if( balance < 0, -balance, iferror(1/0) ) 
      } 
    )( 
      query(aggregated, "select Col1", 0), 
      query(aggregated, "select Col2", 0) 
    ) 
  )( 
    query(
      A3:D, 
      "select A, sum(C) - sum(D) 
       where A is not null 
       group by A 
       label sum(C) - sum(D) '' ", 
      0 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this in cell G2:

`=BYROW(F2:F,LAMBDA(fx,IF(fx="",,LAMBDA(cx,dx,{IF(cx-dx>0,cx-dx,),IF(dx-cx>0,dx-cx,)})(SUMIF(A:A,fx,C:C),SUMIF(A:A,fx,D:D)))))`

-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set a QUERY that finds both entire columns like this:

```
=QUERY(A2:D,"SELECT A,SUM(C)-SUM(D),SUM(D)-SUM(C) where A is not null group by A",1)
```

[image]

And check with LAMBDA if there are negative values and change them to null:

```
=LAMBDA(a,INDEX(IF(a<0,,a)))(QUERY(A2:D,"SELECT A,SUM(C)-SUM(D),SUM(D)-SUM(C) WHERE A is not null group by A",1))
```

[image]

Comment: I put both steps for you to understand the thinking process and be able to replicate in other scenarios, but the second formula works by itself 

Answer (score 0):

If the values in your result table are just for display, you can use the QUERY format clause to hide negative values, such that the whole thing can be generated within a single QUERY:

```
=QUERY(A2:D,"select A,sum(C)-sum(D),sum(D)-sum(C) where A is not null group by A label sum(C)-sum(D) 'Dr',sum(D)-sum(C) 'Cr' format sum(C)-sum(D) '0;',sum(D)-sum(C) '0;'",1)
```